# Assuming a three day fast, what is the percentage of protein burned in the fourth day?

Tags: calories, protein, fat

To give more detail:

- 100kg male
- fast with only water (and salts) and/or coffee allowed
- low activity (computer desk job)

I'd like to keep the muscle loss to a minimum by adding only protein to the 7 day fast.

What is the percent (from the protein + carbs + fat total) of protein burned from muscle loss on a fasting day so I can counter it with added protein?

Comment: If you want to keep muscle loss to a minimum, you’re actually doing the opposite of what you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JustSnilloc please be more verbose.

Comment: If you're adding protein, you are no longer fasting. For what purpose is the 7 day fast?

Comment: @JohnP I've been following Nassim Nicholas Taleb's advice with 1 day / week, 3 days in a row / month and 7 days once a year. Basically trying to get the health benefits of autophagy - letting the cells that should die out, die; increasing insulin sensitivity. I've been doing this for 5 years now.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Just asking "what is the percentage of protein burned" does not make sense, as all protein consumed is burned regardless of whether you are fasting or not, in the sense that it has caloric value and you are consuming it.

Comment: What is the percent of protein burned from muscle loss on a fasting day so I can counter it with added protein?

@DavidScarlett

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. The question is unclear and most likely can not be answered the way ist is asked right now.

Comment: @StefanS Percentage of what? When you eat nothing There is glycogen, fat and different types of tissue. We do not know when your glycogen stores are empty so that you will run on fat and protein only. There are also no studies known to me about the rate of muscle loss (especially not measured in grams of protein) while fasting. Please make clear what you are asking and that it can actually be answered which does not seem to be the case